# Identification and Effectiveness of excercise

Tags: exercise, muscle, chest

I saw this exercise and i cant remember where but it is a chest exercise,
 You lie down on floor, put dumbbell on your chest, grab it firmly with both hands in middle and raise it to top and them back again to chest and so on.
I this exercise legitimate and is it effective for chest?

Comment: Was it the Hex Press? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMHbzfWcUyg - It's doable both on a bench and on the floor.

Comment: does it really work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X54ZWq8lEUU) (@5'30) describes the exercise you want. It also describes the way you can use it to target the chest. One exercise can target different muscles depending on how you use it i.e. changing little details can change the targeted muscles

Comment: You should have mentioned that the exercise in question is the dumbbell pullover.

Comment: I did not know the name. Just the purpose of the exercise